# Matlab error in setup of MIT's Spheres Simulation

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, matlab, cmake

I am trying to run MIT's spheres simulation on my computer. For this, first I downloaded the zip file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/issspheres/. After that, according to the pdf file named "SPHERES Simulation Installation Manual" in "SPHERES_Simulation_R3.zip\SPHERES_Simulation_R3\SimDocumentation" I tried to set up the simulation. Up to page 14 of this manual everything seems fine. On page 14, it says "type rebuildAll". And when I type "rebuildAll" everything is still fine. The next command is, as stated on the same page, writing "cfg = configureSim();BuildSimulation(cfg);". But when I type this I faced with "Error: could find generator in Cache" on matlab command window. I believe it is something related to cmake and visual studio 2010 but I could not figure it out.

I actually asked this question before but with little information I guess. Therefore, it is somehow deleted from here. This time, I hope I clearly explained. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the problem myself after a long time. And I am writing here how I solved the problem for possible needs in the future.

The reason I was getting the error "Error: could find generator in Cache" after typing "cfg = configureSim();BuildSimulation(cfg);" is CMake had used "Visual Studio 10" instead of "Visual Studio 10 Win64" as generator while trying to build the source code from directory "C:/spheres/trunk/MatlabSim/CSPHERESCore/SimVerification" to directory "C:/spheres/trunk/MatlabSim/CSPHERESCore/SimVerification/build". Therefore the "build" file was empty and I was getting that error.

After changing generator from "Visual Studio 10" to "Visual Studio 10 Win64" and configuring again, required files were generated in "build" file. After that I successfully finished installing the SPHERES Simulation. Here, I am writing step by step how I solved the problem.

(i) From start menu I clicked on CMake (cmake-gui)

(ii) On that gui, I clicked on the "Browse Source" button and chose "C:/spheres/trunk/MatlabSim/CSPHERESCore/SimVerification"

(iii) Then I clicked on the "Browse Build" button and chose "C:/spheres/trunk/MatlabSim/CSPHERESCore/SimVerification/build"

(iv) After that, I arranged generator as "Visual Studio 10 Win64" instead of "Visual Studio 10"

(v) Finally I pressed the button "Configure".

Then I went back to Matlab and followed the remaining steps and installed the SPHERES Simulation.